# Spring Boot works on Other Local Computers but not mine IntelliJ, Bean Factory not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Spring Boot with IntelliJ Java 8. For some reason the Bean Factory is working on all other teammates computers from Git, except my local computer. I am receiving the following errors. It's like it cannot initialize the Beans.  I cleared, invalidated caches, and restarted Intellij. Still no luck. Does anyone know what the issue can be?

```
2021-09-02 12:26:49.213  INFO 2430 --- [           main] c.k.s.s.c.capture.server.Application     : Starting Application using Java 1.8.0_73 on KMAC-15SJGH5 with PID 2430 (/Users/joe/src/charge-capture/service/service-server/target/classes started by joe in /Users/joe/src/charge-capture)
2021-09-02 12:26:49.217  INFO 2430 --- [           main] c.k.s.s.c.capture.server.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-02 12:26:51.689  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-02 12:26:51.690  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-02 12:26:51.721  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-02 12:26:51.742  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-02 12:26:51.744  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-02 12:26:51.768  INFO 2430 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2021-09-02 12:26:52.197  INFO 2430 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=43442f9b-fc6e-3ab1-be0d-b16685f5327e
2021-09-02 12:26:52.554  INFO 2430 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.abcd.library.springboot.autoconfigure.config.RedisCacheCon
```

This program does not have errors on other computers, and so its not a source code problem, more of an environmental issue with my local.

Active profiles does not seem like the issue, as it has a select  mechanism here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    String[] profiles = SpringProfilesUtil.readActiveProfiles(Application.class);
    if(profiles != null) {
        springApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(profiles);
    }
    springApplication.run(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not locate Maven Window even though the Plugin was installed.
Right Click on the root pom.xml file and select "Add as Maven Project" from the context menu. After this, application should run without Bean errors.

Not sure why it fixed the issue, however could be a small issue with IntelliJ. Either way, it works.